# Micrometer with Prometheus Pushgateway - Add TLS Support

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a Spring boot application with Prometheus Pushgateway using Micrometer, mainly based on this tutorial:
https://luramarchanjo.tech/2020/01/05/spring-boot-2.2-and-prometheus-pushgateway-with-micrometer.html

`pom.xml` has following related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And `application.properties` file has:

```
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.shutdown-operation=PUSH
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.baseUrl=localhost:9091
```

It is working fine locally in Dev environment while connecting to Pushgateway without any TLS. In our CI environment, Prometheus Pushgateway has TLS enabled. How do I configure TLS support and configure certs in this Spring boot application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the usage of TLS, you will need to customize a few Spring classes:

- [HttpConnectionFactory](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/HttpConnectionFactory.html) -> [PushGateway](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/PushGateway.html) -> [PrometheusPushGatewayManager](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.7.3/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusPushGatewayManager.html)

A `HttpConnectionFactory`, is used by prometheus' `PushGateway` to create a secure connection, and then, create a `PrometheusPushGatewayManager` which uses the previous pushgateway.

You will need to implement the prometheus’ interface `HttpConnectionFactory`, I’m assuming you are able to create a valid *javax.net.ssl.SSLContext* object (if not, more details in the end¹).

**HttpConnectionFactory** example:

```java
public class MyTlsConnectionFactory implements io.prometheus.client.exporter.HttpConnectionFactory {
    @Override
    public HttpURLConnection create(String hostUrl) {
        // considering you can get javax.net.ssl.SSLContext or javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
        URL url = new URL(hostUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**PushGateway** and **PrometheusPushGatewayManager**:

```java
@Bean 
public HttpConnectionFactory tlsConnectionFactory() {
    return new MyTlsConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean 
public PushGateway pushGateway(HttpConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws MalformedURLException {
    String url = "https://localhost:9091"; // replace by your props
    PushGateway pushGateway = new PushGateway(new URL(url));
    pushGateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory); 
    return pushGateway;
}

@Bean 
public PrometheusPushGatewayManager tlsPrometheusPushGatewayManager(PushGateway pushGateway,
                                                                    CollectorRegistry registry) {
    // fill the others params accordingly (the important is pushGateway!)
    return new PrometheusPushGatewayManager(
            pushGateway,
            registry,
            Duration.of(15, ChronoUnit.SECONDS),
            "some-job-id",
            null,
            PrometheusPushGatewayManager.ShutdownOperation.PUSH
    );
}
```

---

¹If you face difficulty retrieving the SSLContext from java code, I recommend studying the library https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart and https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl (which shows how to apply it with different client libs).

Then, will be possible to generate SSLContext in java code in a clean way, e.g.:

```java
String keyStorePath = "client.jks";
char[] keyStorePassword = "password".toCharArray();
SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
        .withIdentityMaterial(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword)
        .build();
javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslContext = sslFactory.getSslContext();
```

Finally, if you need setup a local Prometheus + TLS environment for testing purposes, I recommend following the post:
https://smallstep.com/hello-mtls/doc/client/prometheus